# SOQL Tables related by a common look up field

Tags: apex, soql, b2b-commerce

Basically I am trying to get records from ProductCategoryProduct and from CartItem, both tables have a lookup field to Product2, so I use that table.

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Id FROM CartItem),
(SELECT ProductCategory.Name FROM ProductCategoryProducts)
FROM Product2
```

With ProductCategoryProduct it works correctly. But with CartItem it doesn't.
I get the error :

```
"SELECT Name, (SELECT Id FROM CartItem), 
ERROR at Row:1:Column:30
Didn't understand relationship 'CartItem' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting....blah blah"
```

[image]
[image]
what am I missing here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the child relationship name is not correct. I don't have B2B Commerce Cloud activated in any of my orgs, but this is a generic solution:

The best way to find the correct child relationship name is (in my opinion) the Workbench app.

- Log in to your instance, then go to workbench.developerforce.com.
- Log in with the same credentials as your SF instance, then go to info->Standard & Custom Objects -> select Product2 -> go to Child Relationships

From there you will have a list of all child relationships you can use in your SOQL queries, and each relationship will have a relationshipName that you can use in your subquery.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Guy Clairbois , 
Relationship is there, but unlike others there is no relationship child for this one

```CartItem.Product2Id
    cascadeDelete: false
    childSObject: CartItem
   deprecatedAndHidden: false
   field: Product2Id```

This is the relation for ProductCategoryProduct

```ProductCategoryProduct.ProductId
cascadeDelete: false
childSObject: ProductCategoryProduct
deprecatedAndHidden: false
field: ProductId
relationshipName: ProductCategoryProducts```

Comment: That might mean that the relationship is somehow not queryable. Unfortunately, strange contructions like this exist in more places in the 'standard object' datamodel. There is a small chance this is an unintended behaviour, i.e. a bug. You could try to find out by logging a case with SF support.